# Animation issues on MS Surface

Tags: c#, animation, windows-runtime

I am trying to animate ScrollViewer like this:

```
var anim = new DoubleAnimation
{
    From = from,
    To = to,
    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)),
    EnableDependentAnimation = true
};

// run animation
var sb = new Storyboard();
sb.Children.Add(anim);
Storyboard.SetTarget(anim, SmoothScrollViewer);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, "(ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset)");
sb.Begin();
```

It works fine when run on my desktop, but does not work when run on Surface Pro device. Looks loke animations just ignored, because if I add listener to Storyboard.Completed event, it raises. How can I fix or workaround this issue?

Answer (score 0):

That can't possibly work because `HorizontalOffset` is read-only. If you're targeting Windows 8.1 - the [`ChangeView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn252763.aspx) method animates scroll by default. If your app needs to work on 8.0 you can animate another property and call `ScrollToHorizontalOffset()` in that property's change handler (or use [my extensions](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Controls/Extensions/ScrollViewerExtensions.cs) to do it).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'll try to animate another property. But, anyway, my method is working on my desktop — bug in framework?

Comment: Not sure. Can you share a repro project?